# floating divs disrupting page flow

Tags: html, css

basically i'm trying to keep the flow of the page.

For my content I have:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="adsense1">
  </div>
  <div id="mainContentSpace">
      <div id="mainContent">
      </div>
      <div id="feed">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="adsense2">
  </div>
</div>

<div id=something">
<div>
```

css:

```
#content { width: 1240px;}

#adsense1 { width: 1240px;}

#mainContentSpace { width: 1240px;}

#mainContent { float: left; position: relative; width: 900px; background-color: blue;}

#feed { float: left; width: 300px; height: 600px; background-color: red;}

#adsense2 { width: 1240px;}
```

The problem is that whatever I put inside the something div, it displays on page next to floated elements. I'm hoping that I can avoid setting heights on the divs that don't have height, and still keep the flw of the page normal.

Can anyone tell me if there is a way of keeping the following divs in place after the floated divs without setting heights. That is if there is a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code, take a look.

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
   <div id="adsense1">
</div>
<div id="mainContentSpace">
  <div id="mainContent">
  </div>
  <div id="feed">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="adsense2">
</div>
<div class="clearer"></div>
</div>

<div id=something">
    TEST
<div>
```

CSS:

```
#content { width: 1240px; border: 3px solid orange;}

#adsense1 { width: 1240px;}

#mainContentSpace { width: 1240px;}

#mainContent { float: left; width: 900px; height: 600px; background-color: blue;  1px solid green;}

#feed { float: left; width: 340px; height: 600px; background-color: red;}

#adsense2 { width: 1240px;}

div.clearer{
    clear: both;    
}
```

Conclusion, You should clear floating after divs, common method is creating div with CSS **clear: both;** property and placing it after floating divs. Also, You can use this approach without specifing heights but you need some content inside your divs!

Comment: great thanks. I still hadn't found out what clear actually did.

Comment: The clear property specifies on which sides of an element floating is not allowed. `clear: both` do not allow floating on left or right side of an element. Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)